# Pulling distinct values for individuals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, distinct

I am trying to get a read out of all patients with a result in any of the 4 axis categories on their most recent date from proc_chron and where the patient is a(active) under their case_status well excluding patients where all four categories are null. SQL server 2005.

```
select 

pct.patient_id,
pct.clinic_id,
pct.axis_I_II_1,
pct.axis_I_II_2,
pct.axis_I_II_3,
pct.axis_III_1,
pct.proc_chron

from patient_clin_tran pct
join patient p
on p.patient_id = pct.patient_id
group by pct.patient_id, pct.clinic_id, pct.axis_I_II_1,pct.axis_I_II_2, pct.axis_I_II_3, pct.axis_III_1, p.case_status, pct.proc_chron
having p.case_status = 'a' and pct.proc_chron = (select max(pct.proc_chron))
order by pct.patient_id
```

[image]

Comment: Move `pct.proc_chron = (select max(pct.proc_chron)` to WHERE and try.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding what you are saying. I added a where in addition to the having and tried it with the group by and having commented out and it's still not working.

Comment: StevieG has posted what I was asking you to do, see if that works.

Comment: I got an error on what he posted. I posted the error below his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select     
    pct.patient_id,
    pct.clinic_id,
    pct.axis_I_II_1,
    pct.axis_I_II_2,
    pct.axis_I_II_3,
    pct.axis_III_1,
    pct.proc_chron    
from patient_clin_tran pct
    join patient p
    on p.patient_id = pct.patient_id
where p.case_status = 'a' 
    and pct.proc_chron = (select max(proc_chron) from patient_clin_tran pct2 where pct2.patientid = p.patientid)
and (pct.axis_I_II_1 is not null or pct.axis_I_II_2 is not null or pct.axis_I_II_3 is not null or pct.axis_I_II_4 is not null)
order by pct.patient_id
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: That works. Thanks! Any ideas on how to remove ones where all 4 of the axis columns are null?

Comment: @StevieG What is the point of Grouping if no AGGREGATE functions are being used. I think this can be done without the GROUPing.

Comment: It could be done with grouping. He was just reworking my code and I had put it in a million different forms before I posted the one I currently had. Not sure about the all 4 axis columns being NULL thing if anyone has any ideas though. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Edited the answeer slightly - removed the GROUP BY and filtered out the rows with 4 nulls..

Comment: Thanks for the clean up. The Null's didn't do exactly what I want where I needed it to only exclude if all four of the axis categories were null, but I was able to do it real quick in Excel, so I'm all set. Thank you everyone for your help.